# Get notified when the page of UIPageViewController changes

Tags: swift3, uipageviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have ViewController that contains a container. In this container I have a UIPageViewController.
How can I be notified in the mainVC that a page has changed ?

Answer (score 1):

Mine is not the most modern approach, but it works for me.
In the child view controller I have a reference to the parent via:

```
weak var parentDelegate: ParentEventControllerDelegate?
```

and I can even update information in the parent using:

```
addEntry()
```

By creating a protocol that each can use:

```
@objc protocol ParentEventControllerDelegate {
    func eventsForIndex(index: Int) -> [EKEvent]
    func itemsForIndex(index: Int) -> [Item]
}

@objc protocol ChildEventControllerDelegate {
    func addEntry()
}
```